# Notifications about important log records

Tags: notification, error-handling, logs

**Some intro**: I'm new in ubuntu and last one-two months have installed-reinstalled-configured system/apps. And in the end hoping that my environment is finally set i found out that in my important log there are about 10 records only after system startup..

[image]

More than that now i cannot determine after which step of my setup errors occur - after initial setup, installing some app, editing group policies or disable/enable services.

**So that is the question** - is there the way (app, maybe extension?) to do real time notifications of errors? Because 'just write it down somewhere' if something gone wrong is obviously not enough.

Comment: What is the application you are using in your screenshot?

Comment: @stumblebee: it's just built-in `gnome-logs` (I'm running Gnome on Xorg session).

Comment: I had a feeling it was a gnome app. `gnome-system-log` will show the logs in real time.

Comment: @stumblebee: I've installed it and have tested a bit. It really do autoupdate logs in real time (not notification, but something). Bad news is that it's extremely outdated app (about dialog shows 2008 year) and on launching shows bunch of CRITICAL errors (i suppose some of logs are just in other place for now). But i can found there some of records i want to track.. so if the filtering feature will work - it's akin what i was looking for. So - please post your comment as answer so i will accept it in couple of days if nothing better will proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gnome-system-log` displays system log files in real time, you can add or remove any log file from the monitor list and can filter or search expressions in them. When activity is detected, the logfile name changes to bold and the newly added information is also displayed in bold text.

Install [gnome-system-log](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-system-log&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-log
```

Screenshot:

[image]